# how to stop stopwatch during debugging C# and vs2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, stopwatch

So i have some code that depends upon `stopwatch` for some calculations.

However once stopwatch starts it doesn't stop even during debugging and it is creating problems for me when i try to debug the code.

Is there any way that i can stop stopwatch from running during debugging. I am using VS2012.

Comment: Show us what have you done ;)

Comment: well its a rather large code. Just consider that its loop running for some specific time and a variable is being incremented inside it

Comment: Then can you re-create what you are trying to accomplish in a small sandbox program? Nvoigt is right in his answer, Stopwatch just records the start time, then compares the stop time, there is no "running count" to stop when you break. If you can show us what you are attempting to do, maybe we can give you something to use in Stopwatch's place. Stopwatch is [Wall Clock Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) based not [CPU Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time) based.

Comment: Can you not use the Immediate window to stop your stopwatch?

Comment: well it was months ago and now i don't remember what i did to remedy the situation.

Comment: There are some ideas here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398393/how-to-ignore-the-passage-of-time-while-debugger-has-code-paused

Answer (score 6):

No you can't. Because a stopwatch isn't actually *running* like a thread that you could pause and resume. It's simply taking the time at start and the time at stop and calculating the difference.

Maybe if you post your code or concept, we could find a way to solve your problem without a stopwatch?

Comment: If you vote something down, please leave a comment, so the poster can improve.

Comment: its a loop running for some specific time and variables are being incremented inside it.

Comment: The answer's correct but the reasoning isn't accurate.  A Stopwatch *can* be paused and resumed by calling the `Stopwatch.Stop` and `Stopwatch.Start` methods.  But it's not really feasible or desirable to expect the debugger to call into your application code to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not what you were hoping for, but you can temporarily do this:

```
stopwatch.Stop();
Debugger.Break();
stopwatch.Start();
```

you could wrap it in #if DEBUG block if you don't want to worry about accidentally leaving it in.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following, if you run using the Debug profile in VS2012:

```
#if DEBUG
sw.Stop();
#endif
```

Comment: Supposedly he means stopping the time for the whole universe (of the application), so no thread is running, no stopwatch is running, no timeout is expiring etc until next debugging step is performed...

Answer (score -1):

use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` for this.

> **Debugger.Break:** If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they
>   want to attach a debugger. If yes, the debugger is started. If a
>   debugger is attached, the debugger is signaled with a user breakpoint
>   event, and the debugger suspends execution of the process just as if a
>   debugger breakpoint had been hit.

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: Stopwatch is still running