# How would I implement a DateTime.UtcNow that factors-in debugger pauses?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, time

Consider:

```
public static void Main()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    String x = Console.ReadLine(); // <-- breakpoint on this line
    DateTime then = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

If I run this program in a debugger with a breakpoint on the `Console.ReadLine()` call and let the debugger pause the program for 30 seconds before manually resuming, then the `then` value would be `now + 30s`. This may affect debugging timing-related bugs that use of the debugger might not detect because the time the program was paused is still added to `DateTime.Utc` because it represents wall-clock time.

I'm after a way to get the value of `DateTime.UtcNow` as if the program wasn't paused for those 30 seconds, that way I could abstract-away `DateTime.UtcNow`. For example, if `System.Diagnostics.Debugger` had this functionality:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

private static DateTime _lastPaused      = DateTime.UtcNow;
private static TimeSpan _pauseAdjustment = TimeSpan.Zero;

public static void Main()
{
    Debugger.OnPause => { _lastPaused = DateTime.UtcNow; };
    Debugger.OnResume => { _pauseAdjustment += DateTime.UtcNow - _lastPaused;  };

    DateTime now = GetDebuggerUtcNow();
    String x = Console.ReadLine(); // <-- breakpoint on this line
    DateTime then = GetDebuggerUtcNow();
}

private static DateTime GetDebuggerUtcNow()
{
    return DateTime.UtcNow - _pauseAdjustment;
}
```

This isn't the same thing as getting "cpu time" because this value does not necessarily have a relation to the number of CPU cycles or instructions it took to run, for example, time spent waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.

But of course, `Debugger.OnPause` and `Debugger.OnResume` don't exist - so is there another approach?

Comment: This is going to be difficult and messy, i assume you have seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398393/how-to-ignore-the-passage-of-time-while-debugger-has-code-paused

Comment: @TheGeneral No, I didn't. Thank you for finding it as I did spend a while looking to see if my question was a duplicate but I guess I was using different search terms.

Comment: All good, yeah its hit and miss sometimes when you are trying to find things, though still, a solution to your problem is going to be hard to realize reliably